# opengl - spot light moves when camera rotates when using a shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, light

I implemented a simple shader for the lighting; it kind of works, but the light seems to move when the camera rotates (and only when it rotates).

I'm experimenting with a spotlight, this is how it looks like (it's the spot in the center):
[image]

If now I rotate the camera, the spot moves around; for example, here I looked down (I didn't move at all, just looked down) and it seemed at my feet:
[image]

I've looked it up and I've seen that it's a common mistake when mixing reference systems in the shader and/or when setting the light's position before moving the camera.

The thing is, I'm pretty sure I'm not doing these two things, but apparently I'm wrong; it's just that I can't find the bug.

Here's the shader:

**Vertex Shader**

```
varying vec3 vertexNormal;
varying vec3 lightDirection;

void main()
{
    vertexNormal = gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal;

    lightDirection = vec3(gl_LightSource[0].position.xyz - (gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex).xyz);

    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

**Fragment Shader**

```
uniform vec3 ambient;
uniform vec3 diffuse;
uniform vec3 specular;
uniform float shininess;

varying vec3 vertexNormal;
varying vec3 lightDirection;

void main()
{
    vec3 color = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

    vec3 lightDirNorm;
    vec3 eyeVector;
    vec3 half_vector;
    float diffuseFactor;
    float specularFactor;
    float attenuation;
    float lightDistance;

    vec3 normalDirection = normalize(vertexNormal);

    lightDirNorm = normalize(lightDirection);

    eyeVector = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    half_vector = normalize(lightDirNorm + eyeVector);

    diffuseFactor = max(0.0, dot(normalDirection, lightDirNorm));

    specularFactor = max(0.0, dot(normalDirection, half_vector));
    specularFactor = pow(specularFactor, shininess);

    color += ambient * gl_LightSource[0].ambient;
    color += diffuseFactor * diffuse * gl_LightSource[0].diffuse;
    color += specularFactor * specular * gl_LightSource[0].specular;

    lightDistance = length(lightDirection[i]);

    float constantAttenuation = 1.0;
    float linearAttenuation = (0.02 / SCALE_FACTOR) * lightDistance;
    float quadraticAttenuation = (0.0 / SCALE_FACTOR) * lightDistance * lightDistance;

    attenuation = 1.0 / (constantAttenuation + linearAttenuation + quadraticAttenuation);

    // If it's a spotlight
    if(gl_LightSource[i].spotCutoff <= 90.0) 
    {
        float spotEffect = dot(normalize(gl_LightSource[0].spotDirection), normalize(-lightDirection));
        if (spotEffect > gl_LightSource[0].spotCosCutoff) 
        {
            spotEffect = pow(spotEffect, gl_LightSource[0].spotExponent);

            attenuation = spotEffect / (constantAttenuation + linearAttenuation + quadraticAttenuation);
        }
        else
            attenuation = 0.0;
    }

    color = color * attenuation;

    // Moltiplico il colore per il fattore di attenuazione
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

Now, I can't show you the code where I render the things, because it's a custom language which integrates opengl and it's designed to create 3D applications (it wouldn't help to show you); but what I do is something like this:

```
SetupLights();
UpdateCamera();
RenderStuff();
```

Where:

- SetupLights contains actual opengl calls that setup the lights and their positions;
- UpdateCamera updates the camera's position using the built-in classes of the language; I don't have much power here;
- RenderStuff calls the built-in functions of the language to draw the scene; I don't have much power here either.

So, either I'm doing something wrong in the shader or there's something in the language that "behind the scenes" breaks things.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

you wrote

> the light's position is already in *world coordinates*, and that is where I'm doing the computations

however, since you're applying gl_ModelViewMatrix to your vertex and gl_NormalMatrix to your normal, these values are probably in view space, which might cause the moving light.

as an aside, your eye vector looks like it should be in view coordinates, however, view space is a right-handed coordinate system, so "forward" points along the negative z-axis. also, your specular computation will likely be off since you're using the same eye vector for all fragments, but it should probably point towards that fragment's position on the near/far planes.

Comment: My mistake, the position of the light is in view space in the shader.
I think you're right about the other things, but still the can't find the real problem.

Comment: If your light position is in view space, you'll have to update it whenever the camera changes. Your sequence of `SetupLights()` before `UpdateCamera()` seems to be conceptually wrong for that.